# convert raw image bytes to multipage tiff using java and vice versa

Tags: java, tiff

I have a requirement where i have set of base64 strings each string is one tiff file, i need to combine all these base64 strings and provide this full tiff data as base64 string, so end user can create a tiff file from the combined base64 strings.

I tried all the ways shared below but each time in my output tiff only one page is coming but i am passing 2 base64 strings.

Any inputs greatly appreciated.

Iam using this code

```
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

//this is repetative so i am adding all the base64 strings to arraylist
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(imageObject.get("image").toString());
                                                                                                  al.add(imgBytes);

//writing all base64 strings to a new tiff file //here it is showing only the first page but in the top i am adding two pages.
BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(toByteArray(al)));
                                                                   ImageIO.write(imag, "tif", new File(processedFilesFolder,"combined.tif"));


public static byte[] toByteArray(List<byte[]> bytesList)
{
    int size = 0;

    for (byte[] bytes : bytesList)
    {
        size += bytes.length;
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

    for (byte[] bytes : bytesList)
    {
        byteBuffer.put(bytes);
    }

    return byteBuffer.array();
}



ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( ); 
outputStream.write( data ); // this line is repetative
byte c[] = outputStream.toByteArray( ); 
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\EID_Image_Desktop‌​Scan_mod.tiff")) { stream.write(c); } catch(Exception e){}
```

Regards,
Meerasaaheb Mohmmad

Comment: I have tried many methods to copy base64 arrays and convert them to tiff. But all the time the generated output file has only the lastly added document in the tiff file.
System.arraycopy() method i tried  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );  outputStream.write( data ); byte c[] = outputStream.toByteArray( );
      try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\EID_Image_DesktopScan_mod.tiff")) {
            stream.write(c);
      }

Comment: Put your code into the question and not in comments. And tell what failed for you and how to fix it.

Comment: Edit your question and add what you have tried to it

Comment: Dears,Thanks for your response, i had edited my question and added the coded i have tried please share your expertise or findings.